# How to lookup by field inherited from OneToOneField of another model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am attempting to lookup `UserProfile` model using a field inherited from the `User` model. How can I access the username field from the `User` model in `UserProfile` view?

I am using Django REST framework 3.9. And from my understanding, using the `@property` annotation in the Model definition allows you to serialize on that field. And I am using that serialized field as `lookup_field` in the view.

This is the `UserProfile` model.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def username(self):
        return self.user.username
```

This is the serializer.

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = [
            'user',
            'username',
            'bio',
            'birth_date'
        ]
```

This is the view.

```
class UserProfileAPIView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    # permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    lookup_field = 'username'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return UserProfile.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_context(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return {'request': self.request}
```

This is the API URL.

```
path('<str:username>/profile/', UserProfileAPIView.as_view(), name='profile'),
```

I expected the API to return `username, bio, birth_date`, but I received this error:

> Cannot resolve keyword 'username' into field. Choices are: bio, birth_date, id, user, user_id

Comment: I think the problem is not with your serializer but with your lookup field. Try considering `lookup_field = 'user__username'`.

Comment: Let me put it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@property` is just a Python calculated field here, which will be available only after the object is available. But to get the objects this cannot be used.

`lookup_field` requires a DB relation. As I said before, we cannot use the `username` property for this. It should be `lookup_field = 'user__username'`.

Answer (score 0):

Add *source* to the Hyperlink identity field.

```
URL = HyperlinkIdentityField(
        view_name='your_view_name',
        source=User,
        lookup_field='username'
      )
```